# Send HTML Formatted Email to Multiple Recipients with Powershell

Tags: html, windows, email, powershell, parameters

I have a PowerShell function which I would like to expand on, but have hit a roadblock with a couple of features.

**End goal**: Send a html formatted email via SMTP with Windows PowerShell to multiple recipients.

**Criteria**:

1. The user must specify either a CSV path to import the relevant variables, or;
2. The user must specify a these variables as parameters.
3. The html file must be external to the script and must contain powershell variables.

**The function so far**:

```
Function Send-HTMLEmail
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$smtpRecipientAddress,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$smtpSubject, 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$smtpFromAddress = 'info@domain.com', 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$smtpServer = 'exchserver', 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$htmlFilePath,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$CSVFile
    )
    $smtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient 
    $mailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage 
    $SmtpClient.Host = $smtpServer 
    $mailMessage.From = $smtpFromAddress 
    $mailMessage.To.add($smtpRecipientAddress)
    $mailMessage.Subject = $smtpSubject
    $mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
    $mailMessage.Body = $emailTemplate
    $smtpClient.Send($mailMessage) 
}
```

1. As you can see, the function has no mandatory parameters. This is easy enough to add, but I'm not sure how to specify either the CSVFile parameter as mandatory or all the others.
2. Below is a rough example of what the html should look like. How can this be imported and the PowerShell variables initialised? (note that the variables in the below email are to be imported from another script, this is unrelated):

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   body {
   background-color: #DEE8F1;
   }
   p.normal {
   font-family: "Calibri";
   color: black;
   font-size: 13px;
   }
   p.normal em{
   font-family: "Calibri";
   color: black;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: bold;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p class="normal"><em>$($user.Name)</em>,<br /><br /> 
   Your password will expire in <em>$($userTable.DaysTillExpiry)</em> days
   on <em>$($userTable.ExpiryDate)</em><br /><br />
   Your domain password is required for Computer Login, remote VPN, 
   and Email Access.<br /><br />
   To change your password, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and choose Change Password.<br /><br>
   For your password to be valid it must be 8 or more characters long and<br />
   contain a mix of the following properties:<br /><br />
   uppercase letters (A-Z)<br />
   lowercase letters (a-z)<br />
   numbers (0-9)<br /><br />
   Regards,<br /><br /><br />
   <em>IT Department</em> <br />
   Ph: +xx xxxx xxxx <br /><br /><br />
   <br /></h1>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is a big one. Not sure I will be able to help you out will all your questions, but let's try. And I won't be able to provide a fully working script, just give you hints on how to figure it out, ok?

First off, to be able to make either csvfile OR all the other parameters mandatory, you should read up on parameter sets. Basically, you assign csvfile to a parameter set, and all the others to a second one. Then you can set the parameters to mandatory, and the users will only be able to either select csvfile or the other parameters.

Second, to be able to read the html from an external file, and still have the variable expanded correctly, you need to read the file like this:

```
$mailBody = Get-Content $htmlFilePath | Foreach-Object {$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
PS> Get-Help Send-MailMessage -Parameter Body

-Body <String>
    Specifies the body (content) of the e-mail message.
    
    Required?                    false
    Position?                    3
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Alright, so you need a String to pass to -Body.

```
Function Get-HTMLvar
{
    [PSCustomObject]
    $user = @{ Name = 'JaneDoe' }

    [PSCustomObject]
    $userTable = @{ DaysTillExpiry = '23'
                ExpiryDate = '2014/11/15' }

$user + $userTable
}


Function Get-HTMLbody
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        #$user Object
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        $user,

        #$userTable Object
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        $userTable
    )

$emailTemplate = "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
            body {
            background-color: #DEE8F1;
            }
            p.normal {
            font-family: `"Calibri`";
            color: black;
            font-size: 13px;
            }
            p.normal em{
            font-family: `"Calibri`";
            color: black;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p class=`"normal`"><em>$($user.Name)</em>,<br /><br /> 
            Your password will expire in <em>$($userTable.DaysTillExpiry)</em> days
            on <em>$($userTable.ExpiryDate)</em><br /><br />
            Your domain password is required for Computer Login, remote VPN, 
            and Email Access.<br /><br />
            To change your password, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and choose Change Password.<br /><br>
            For your password to be valid it must be 8 or more characters long and<br />
            contain a mix of the following properties:<br /><br />
            uppercase letters (A-Z)<br />
            lowercase letters (a-z)<br />
            numbers (0-9)<br /><br />
            Regards,<br /><br /><br />
            <em>IT Department</em> <br />
            Ph: +xx xxxx xxxx <br /><br /><br />
            <br /></h1>
        </body>
        </html>"

Write-Output $emailTemplate
}


Function Send-HTMLemail
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$smtpRecipientAddress = 'Rcpt@domain.local',

        [Parameter()]
        [string]$smtpSubject = 'Subject',

        [Parameter()]
        [string]$smtpFromAddress = 'Admin@domain.local',

        [Parameter()]
        [string]$smtpServer = 'relay.domain.local',
                
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$emailTemplate
    )
    Send-MailMessage -From $smtpFromAddress `
                     -To $smtpRecipientAddress `
                     -SmtpServer $smtpServer `
                     -Body $emailTemplate `
                     -BodyAsHtml `
                     -Subject $smtpSubject `
                     -Verbose
}
```

So,

```
PS> Get-HTMLvar | Get-HTMLbody | Send-HTMLemail
```

will give you

> JaneDoe,
>
> Your password will expire in 23 days on 2014/11/15
>
> Your domain password is required for Computer Login, remote VPN, and Email Access.
>
> [..]

Comment: `The html file must be external to the script and must contain powershell variables.` Not sure about this one yet, but shouldn't be a showstopper.

Comment: @ojk has your fix for ingest with vars. There you go.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

This process worked a treat, but I read in the html file with the following:

    $emailTemplate = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($htmlFilePath) -replace '##smtpRecipientName##', $smtpRecipientName `
                                                                  -replace '##daysTillExpiry##', $daysTillExpiry `                                                                  -replace '##expiryDate##', $expiryDate